# Options for JS Shapefile to geoJSON conversions that allow multiple input files?

Tags: javascript, react

I am looking for JavaScript options that allow me to take a set of shapefiles (the .shp, .shx, .dbf, and what ever other related files) and convert them into geoJSON.

I am then going to take this geoJSON and save it to the database.

I have found a number of options:

1) https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson

2) https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile

I believe number 2 is my best option but I can't seem to confirm that it will allow me to give it more than one shapefile to convert to geoJSON. Do you know of any libraries that allow for multiple shapefile types to be used as input at one time?

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened. But just so you're aware, the `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf`, etc are part of the same shapefile. Most tools expect you to point to the `.shp` and will then look for the remaining files in the same directory (because not all of them are required). The different parts must have the same name (only different in their file extension).

Comment: I thought .shp, .shx, and .dbf were required and there could be more on top of that? That's helpful though, thanks.

Comment: Yes I believe those are the only three required files, and the rest are optional. I think there are about 13 optional files.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, you have such options, 
yes, I agree, 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile 
is  a good one,

https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js

https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson

https://github.com/RandomEtc/shapefile-js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile

Comment: It's probably worth noting that (near the end of 2021...) the package you recommend has not been updated in 4 years.

Comment: yes. it not update for a long time, but it still works like charm.

Comment: The package has at least one dependency that's now flagged as having a security vulnerability.  I haven't checked in with the author but using unsupported packages will often bite you eventually (even though it may take years...)