# How to parse a shapefile with Esri JavaScript API and/or ArcGIS Server?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, parse

I'm developing a webapp that uses the Esri JavaScript API 3.xx (Dojo 1.x) together with an ArcGIS Server 10.6.xx. Until now I was parsing shapefiles in my Java backend that makes use of an offical Esri shapefile reader.

Is there any way to do this with Esri JavaScript API? If not, is there any other plugin/toolset that is recommendable?

Comment: The web mapping API's purpose doesn't include reading shapefiles directly. While JavaScript is capable of reading a local shapefile, using a servlet is probably the better architecture

Comment: Sounds like this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259551/options-for-js-shapefile-to-geojson-conversions-that-allow-multiple-input-files